# can local images be set as a wallpaper in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have fix amount of images in my application.
and I want to set one of the images as a wallpaper
can I set it as a wallpaper?
Is it possible in iphone application?

if yes the plz give me code.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Its not possible. May be it possible only in Jail Broken iOS Devices..

Answer (score 0):

If you are having Images in your Resources that is in your app then you can do that in this way.

**Adding a Image as a wallpaper in one of your View Controller...**

Go to the XIB of that ViewController open the Library and in Library open the MEDIA Tab.It has all the Images from your Resources.Drag And place that image on your ViewController and Save it. And That's all.

Hope that is what u want... :)